# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1+5^n}{1+6^n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question** 
Use appropriate tests to decide whether the series converges or diverges
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1+5^n}{1+6^n}$$

I'm not sure how to complete this question. I have attempted to complete this with the ratio test, however this becomes very messy quickly.

If it is the right method, can someone show me how to do it, otherwise how would you figure this out?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1 +5^{n+1}}{1+6^{n+1}} \frac{1+6^n}{1+5^n}\right)$$

Comment: Firstly you should determine how the ratio behaves (equivalent), and then you should be able to go back to a series of reference (geometric)

Comment: No, we haven't been taught this. Tests that we have been taught were, alternating series, ratio, integral, comparison

Comment: @tompo, it should converge by the ratio test. Perhaps show us your work? (edit your question and write till the place where you don't know what to do)

Comment: All of those tests look like overkill to me.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to note that every term of the series is positive, so if we can bound the terms from above by the terms of a convergent series, that will prove the series converges. Try filling in the blanks:
$$\frac{1+5^n}{1+6^n}=\frac ? {1+6^n}+\frac {?}{1+6^n}<\frac ? ?+\frac ??$$

Answer (score 4):

It is not that messy...
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{1+5^{n+1}}{1+6^{n+1}}\frac{1+6^{n}}{1+5^{n}} = \frac{1+6^{n}}{1+6^{n+1}}\frac{1+5^{n+1}}{1+5^{n}} = \frac{6^n(6^{-n}+1)}{6^n(6^{-n}+6)}\frac{5^n(5^{-n}+5)}{5^n(5^{-n}+1)} = \frac{6^{-n}+1}{6^{-n}+6}\frac{5^{-n}+5}{5^{-n}+1}.$$
As $n\rightarrow\infty$, $6^{-n},5^{-n}\rightarrow 0$, and thus the limit of the ratio test is $\frac{5}{6}$. Conclude that ...

Comment: .. series converges since <1

Comment: @tompo Yes, exactly.

Comment: @tompo, it is good attitute to "accept" an answer if said answer solved your problem. You should perhaps "accept" this answer.